# Filename is not displayed cleanly in project list in Android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, ide

I am using Android Studio version 2.2.2 and have updated all sdk.

After running Android studio, I can not understand why the last character or 2 characters of file or package name are cut off or overlapped as shown in the screenshot below.

I want to know how it can be displayed clearly.

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: reopen as and see  maybe try to invalidate cache and restart

Comment: @CharukaSilva Thank you I tried, but the problem was not solved.

Comment: you mean like this? File > Invalidate Caches>Restart. or just close and open ?

Comment: @CharukaSilva YES! 'File'->'invalidate caches/restart'

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved.

'File'->'Appearance & Behavior'->'Appearance'->'UI Options'->Checked 'Override default fonts by(not recommended)'

and

change font to 'Source code Pro'